# SharePoint FormField doesn't show the content in ControlMode="Display"

Tags: sharepoint, formfield

I use SharePoint 2010 Standard Edition.

I have custom form for creating/editing items, and few fields with ControlMode="Display", like:

```
<SharePoint:FieldLabel ID="CustomStatusLabel" runat="server" FieldName="CustomStatus" ControlMode="Display" />
<SharePoint:FormField ID="CustomStatusField" runat="server" FieldName="CustomStatus" ControlMode="Display" />
```

When I open this form, all fields which are in ControlMode="Edit" displayed properly, but CustomStatus field is displayed exactly like this:

**Custom Status ["Custom Status" column value]**

Strangely enough, I saw this custom form working on different server...